# Can I get the name of the model class by the table name?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

Let's say I have this Eloquent Model Class:

```
class Fruit extends Model
{
    //whatever not following the conventions
    protected $table = 'the_fruit_table'; 
}
```

And somewhere in my code I have a variable with the table name

```
$table_name = 'the_fruit_table';
```

Is there a way to get the name of the model who's responsible for that table? 
So in this case I would get the string:

```
'\App\Fruit'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the laravel naming conventions you might try the following

```
$class = '\YourModelsNamespace\' . studly_case(str_singular($table))
```

Comment: i would need to get the name of the model even if I don't follow the naming convention. I've edited my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Above should work for the updated table name as well as long as your model names are singular and uses studly case. Eg. `the_fruit_table` => `TheFruitTable`, `my_tables` => `MyTable`, `tables` => `Table`,

Comment: If you follow any other naming convention let me know if I could edit it to match yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default naming system you can get the class name like so:

```
$class = 'App\\'.ucwords(rtrim(camel_case($table_name),'s'));
```

Then check if the class exists:

```
if(class_exists($class)){
    //do something
}
```

And finally you can get use it this way:

```
$result = $class::all()
```

Comment: i would need to get the name of the model even if I don't follow the naming convention. I've edited my question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible:

```
$className = \Propel::getDatabaseMap()->getTable('the_fruit_table')->getClassName();
```

But:

1) FruitPeer must have been (auto)loaded because in the end of BaseFruitPeer there is magic line:

```
BaseFruitPeer::buildTableMap();
```

2) This example assumes you are using default database. If you are not, then you must feed it into getDatabaseMap().

Propel is just full of surprises.